# Question about CronTrigger - Quartz

Tags: java, triggers, quartz-scheduler

Concerning http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/wikidocs/CronTriggers%20Tutorial.html .. given bunch of examples and I just don't get this, how would I write CronTrigger expression to run every minute of every day for unlimited amount of time. I've "figured" out about running it every second which is easy `"* * * * * ?"` how would I write expression which runs every minute lets say..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
0 * * * * ?
```

That means "the zero'th second of every minute"